# How to simplify this expression?

Tags: haskell

Consider this:

```
map fromEnum $ zipWith (==) "aaaa" "abaa"
-- [1,0,1,1]
```

It would be nice to have only one step here:

```
zipWith (\x y -> fromEnum (x == y)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

Now I can eliminate `y`:

```
zipWith (\x -> fromEnum.(x ==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

But I fail to eliminate `x`. Of course there are ways to "cheat"...

```
zipWith (curry (fromEnum . uncurry (==))) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

... but this looks uglier than the original lambda.

The function I look for would be somewhat similar to `Data.Function.on`, but "the other way around". I have the feeling that there is an embarrassingly simple solution for this. Do I overlook something?

Comment: Are you concerned about efficiency or readability?

Comment: If you ask me, I find the first one the most readable. Maybe written like this: `map fromEnum . zipWith (==) $ "aaaa" "abaa"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
zipWith (\x -> fromEnum . (x ==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

can be written as

```
zipWith (\x -> (fromEnum .) (x ==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

which can be written as

```
zipWith ((fromEnum .) . (==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

If you find this readable depends on taste I guess.

EDIT: Another nice way to do it is with [some combinators by Matt Hellige](http://matt.immute.net/content/pointless-fun):

```
zipWith ((==) $. id ~> id ~> fromEnum) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

Comment: When I look at this example I wonder why there is no combinator of type `(a -> a -> b) -> (b -> c) -> a -> a -> c` in the style of the combinator `on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c` from `Data.Function`.

Comment: You can define it as .: = fmap fmap fmap.

Answer (score 3):

There are no predefined library functions that do exactly this kind of function composition you want here. But if you are often using constructs like the one in the question, you could define such a function:

```
(.:) :: (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
g .: f = \x y -> g (f x y)

x = zipWith (fromEnum .: (==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```

Comment: Also known as the "Scaramanga" or "boobs" combinator: `(.:) = (.) . (.)`

Answer (score 1):

I have defined following two combinators for prettifying sections of `(.)`:

1. `(|.>)`: You can read the following definition as, slice `f` on right and compose with `g`.

   ```
   (|.>) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a' -> b) -> (a -> a' -> c)
   f |.> g = (f .) . g
   ```
2. `(<.|)`: You can read the following definition as, slice `g` on left and compose with `f`.

   ```
   (<.|) :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a' -> b) -> (a -> a' -> c)
   f <.| g = (. g) . f
   ```

The direction of arrow indicates the direction in which composition is taking place. Of these two combinators, the first one can be used in your example as follows:

```
zipWith (fromEnum |.> (==)) "aaaa" "abaa"
```